# appendable and greppable archive on CentOS to hold many log files (logrotate on steroids)

Tags: backup, software-rec, compression, logrotate

I have a bunch of applications on a CentOS 6.3 box, which generate daily logs (text files with a very similar content) in this vein:

```
/data/logs/app/my-2014-06-29.log
/data/yet_another_app/logs/catalina.20140629
/data/in_fact/there_are/around_500_such_paths/2014-06-29-1.log
```

I need to keep 5 years of these logs.
I currently treat them in a traditional Unix way, just compressing them in place (as `.log.bz2`), but I'm unhappy they still occupy a lot of space. I feel I could save a lot of space but compacting them and then compressing (think one giant .zip that holds entire year of logs).

Requirements:

### RHEL kosher

No "compile from source" please. If it isn't mature enough to be distributed in an .rpm then it's not for me.

### grep

Archive should allow a recursive grep (like `grep -rli`):

```
grep_my_zip  -rli  pattern   /this/and/that/wildcards/2014-06-*
```

The archive shouldn't de-compress everything when grepping, just the files that match a wildcard.

### append

Each week I'm putting my files into the *same* archive and deleting them from filesystem:

```
append_and_remove   $( find /this/and/that  -name '*.log' -type f -mtime +31 )     # weekly log cleaning job
```

This is not the weekly archive, I want to append to a single big yearly archive each week.

### MS Windows access

Archive, while mainly operated on CentOS Linux, should also allow a single file retrieval on Windows for emergency purposes (so a squashfs-style filesystem is not a viable option).

### Optional stuff (a plus, but not neccessary)

- append should be space effective - consider that previous log files are very similar to the current log files
- logrotate integration for the weekly job
- grep_my_zip that works on Windows
- archive could also be updateable (i.e. writable), not only appendable

Originally posted [on this pitiful sibling](https://superuser.com/questions/774777/appendable-and-greppable-archive-on-centos-to-hold-many-log-files-logrotate-on)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My research on various compressors show that space saving is not worth going into the non-traditional path.

- 8800M unpacked bi-weekly input (5842 files)
- 270M just bzip2 (traditional logrotate style - separate .log.bz2 files)
- 257M tar bzip2
- 400M zip
- 132M p7zip (Windows .7z compatible)
- 140M tar xz
- 129M tar lrzip